Agregar atributo personalizado a colección retornada por Laravel Eloquent
Tengo la siguiente consulta con Eloquent:
User::find(1)

Esto me retorna los datos del usuario:
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'John Doe',
]

Me gustaría agregar un atributo dinámico cuando se haga esta consulta, por ejemplo, agregar la cantidad de posts y que se vea de la siguiente forma:
[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'num_posts' => 6,
]

He intentato con los accesores/mutadores, pero solo funcionan cuando explicitamente se ejecutan, dicho de otro modo User::find(1)->num_posts;
Lo que quiero es que al buscar cualquier usuario ya venga ese atributo en la colección.
(Código NO funcional pero usado como referencia de lo deseado):
User::where('name', 'John')->append([
    'num_posts' => Post::where('user_id', 1)->count()
])->get()

Espero haberme hecho entender y agreadezco su ayuda y comentarios; muchas gracias.

Tendrías que definir el accesor en el modelo user
public function getNumPostsAttribute() {
  return Post::where('user_id', $this->id)->count()
}

Y en al atributo appends del modelo añadir num_posts
protected $appends = [`num_posts`]

